# Gnu make on Windows 7 64bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, gnu-make

I'm migrating from Windows-32 XP to Windows 7 64bit and have problems with my project build. Error appears on very first step - on directory creation. I tried both MinGW and MSYS makes, 32bit and 64bit. It seems that no one can't call md command. Here is very simple Makefile I created to localise problem:

```
all:
md C:\_test\trunk\build\win32
```

MinGW ([mingw-w64's toolchains targetting Win64](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/)) make:

```
C:\_tmp>C:\mingw64\bin\mingw32-make.exe
md C:\_test\trunk\build\win32
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, md C:\_test\trunk\build\win32, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

MSYS ([64bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/External%20binary%20packages%20%28Win64%20hosted%29/MSYS%20%2832-bit%29/)) make:

```
C:_tmp>C:\mingw64\msys\bin\make.exe
md C:\_test\trunk\build\win32
make.exe": md: Command not found
make.exe": *** [all] Error 127
```

There is no problem with the same command run from command line:

```
md C:\_test\trunk\build\win32
```

Can someone please recommend any solution? Thank you.

Comment: `md` is a built-in command in Windows' `cmd` shell. So, either change it to `mkdir` (an then you will probably have to use forward slashes (always a good idea anyway)), or tell make to use `cmd` as its shell.

Answer (score 1):

This problem would be fixed in [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/) by using the builtin command (they all start with &):

```
all:
            &mkdir -p C:/_test/trunk/build/win32
```

Though seriously, that's likely not your only problem.  Looks like your PATH is not getting through.  I don't think make would swallow it, probably its already gone in the setup of your Shell.

But I wonder if you're using the MinGW Shell at all, because then you should be using Unix path syntax, like I do in my Makefile snippet above.  Even in {command,cmd}.{com,exe} only when calling exes, you need the backslash.  To make this portable, makepp provides the variable `$/` which is the correct slash for your machine:

```
foo/bar:
            path$/to$/my$/exe some/arg
```

*There is much more to makepp.  Besides doing almost all that GNU make can, there are lots more useful things, and you can even extend your makefiles with some Perl programming.*

Answer (score 0):

It seems GNU make is confused on Windows 7 64-bit when the PATH variable has paths with parenthesis.
A work around is to specify the full path of commands and invoke built-in commands via the shell:

```
MKDIR := C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C MKDIR

all:
    $(MKDIR) C:\_test\trunk\build\win32
```